# ContentDocumentLink trigger context variable trigger.new is not returning correct value in Classic

Tags: apex, trigger, contentdocumentlink

I am having a trigger on ContentDocumentLink object. **The user upload a file from UI in classic on Opportunity object record**. Ideally when he does that, The trigger.new should return two value, one with linkentityId equals to his user recordid and another with Opportunity record.Unfortunately trigger is returning only one. i.e. for **user**

> Strangely, The trigger return two value in trigger.new context
>   variable in Lightning interface and for file inserted via anonymous
>   block.

My trigger is:-

```
trigger ContentDocumentLinkTrigger on ContentDocumentLink (after insert,before delete) {
    if(trigger.isinsert){
       ContentDocumentLinkTriggerHelper.afterinsertFiles(trigger.new);
     }
 }
```

and method is :-

```
public static void afterinsertFiles(List<Contentdocumentlink> newcontent){    
     for(Contentdocumentlink r:newcontent){
        if (r.LinkedEntityId.getSobjectType() == Opportunity.SObjectType) 
           oppSetIds.add(r.LinkedEntityId);
    } 
}
```

> I am not sure what's wrong with Classic or it is working as designed?

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: @Novarg I have mentioned it in the question. The question is what is different in Classic than Lightning in term of Contentdocumentlink trigger.new so that it return different values?

Comment: you only said that you get 2 records in the trigger if you go through lightning or anonymous block, there is no info about classic

Comment: I have updated it.Please check

Comment: @sanketkumar This article talks about deletion https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?language=en_US&type=1&mode=1&id=000312746 while yours talks about insertion. The reason that I put it here is there is clearly a difference in functionality between lightning and classic

Comment: in classic, does the trigger execute twice - each with one record first user, then Oppo) ?